Can healthy adult human beings live life without "beliefs" or "leaps of faith"?
There is a very insightful discussion on epistemological pluralism available at Is it epistemologically self-consistent to use the scientific method to justify some beliefs and non-scientific justifications for others?, from which I highly recommend the accepted answer by @JD. However, I was surprised by the assertions made by this other answer:

Not really.
Science doesn't lead to beliefs.
Science leads to informed, supportable, repeatable/reproducible coherent conclusions.
Beliefs are not typically conclusions, but instead are typically founded by or invoke leaps of faith. A choice to believe.
Some will argue the point... but it is fact that one can live with zero beliefs.

(Emphasis mine.)
Are there any philosophers who have argued along the lines suggested by the answer: that healthy adult human beings can live life in such a way as to only give intellectual assent to propositions properly justified by science, without "beliefs," "leaps of faith," or "choosing to believe" (borrowing expressions from the answer)? Does this epistemological view have a name, and has it been challenged by other philosophers?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This conflict of Reason vs. Faith is central to a lot of the history of philosophy, especially modern philosophy. The consensus many take these days is that this is a false dichotomy to begin with; that reason and faith are one in the same, two manifestations of the same thing, that being, how we assign truth. Hume's problem of infinite recursion highlights this quite well: Given any statement as true, you can always ask why it's true. Given an answer to that question, you can yet again ask why. And you can, of course, do this infinitely. So how do we resolve this? We need premises (assumptions, axioms) that we take as true without justification. This can be seen as a kind of faith. However, these premises are what allow us to give rise to new truths via reason. So, you see, reason cannot exist without faith, nor faith without reason, considering we still must reason what initial premises to adopt (we don't arbitrarily or randomly adopt premises). The keen reader may notice that there is some meta-logic happening here where I am reasoning about reason. This is true. Not only do faith and reason circularly justify each other, but we circularly justify this circular justification.
So, where does truth begin? Does true truth even exist? The answer is no. Importantly, however, I'd argue that this doesn't matter. Logic is an abstraction; it is a tool that we made up to help us understand the world, but it is by no means a necessary part of the world itself. Reality exists whether we apply logic to it or not. We continue to live whether we justify how or why or not. Who's to say reality even follows rules in the first place? It certainly seems like it does, but who are we to say that for certain, from our limited, biased human perspective?
The "solution" is to accept our inherently subjective existence. Imagine you are pure consciousness, born into this world with no influence by others, no external systems of thought, and no conceptual abstractions. All that exists is what you perceive. This, our perception, is all that we can accept as true, not because it is by any objective measure, but because our perception is necessarily all that makes up our reality. There is no reality we can determine truth within without accepting the perception which constructs this reality. Philosophers, in existential crisis, have tried to determine things outside of our perception by constructing a mythical "objective" reality, but this reality does not exist. It does not exist because we can not perceive it.
From this, to determine general truths about the reality we perceive, we must assume things about this reality. For example, that it follows rules in the first place, or that things "cause" each other, etc.
Are these assumptions, along with the assumption that our perception is "true", beliefs or "leaps of faith"? On one hand, you could argue yes, since there is necessarily no basis whatsoever for which we make these assumptions. On the other hand, the idea that there needs to be a basis in the first place is archaic, and lies within previous philosophers' ideas of an "objective" reality. Is assuming something true a "leap of faith" when it's necessary for our concept of truth in the first place? Frankly, the question isn't well-defined, nor does it really matter.
With how you framed the question, the answer is no, but I would argue that the framing itself is the issue at hand, not the question.

Maybe framing is the cause of most problems?

In philosophy, the word "belief" is a general, neutral term for anything a person considers to be true, regardless of how they arrived at that conclusion. "2+2=4" is a belief, the same as "most cats have four legs," "Jesus ascended bodily to heaven," "NASCAR is better than baseball," or "the moon is made of cheese."
In some other contexts some people attach a religious connotation of "faith" to belief. In philosophy the word is more neutral. There is a need for a general term for anything held to be true regardless of the type of justification.

So it basically means, "I am less than 100% certain." Which covers a lot of ground.

@ScottRowe Even if they are 100% certain, that's still called a belief.

@ScottRowe Knowledge (in philosophical parlance) is a subset of belief, not distinct from it.

"It ain't what you don't know that gets you into trouble. It's what you know for sure that just ain't so.” Certainty is nice, but doesn't mean you are correct, so I see your point.

I believe something to be true based on the evidence that has been presented to me.  This does not make something true or false, but rather demonstrates my perspective. I believe that a certain mathematical proof, and a series of practical experiments represents evidence that gravity does indeed exist.

The OP question is readily answered with a "no".
No, science cannot lead to a life without beliefs, because of:

Science does not justify itself.  The justification of science is through philosophy, and the utility of empiricism as a method of discovery, and the utility of formalizing empiricism to science in some cases.  And none of these justifications rationally close.  Getting TO science requires beliefs.
Very little of life can be lived solely off of science.  Wake up in the morning, where are you?  What is that weight on you?  What is that feeling in your gut?  Can you get up, rely upon the ground not to give way, etc.?  NONE of what you do the first 15 minutes after awakening is based on demonstrated consensus science - it is instead based on informal first person empiricism!

There are probably more points I could cite with more thought, but these two are sufficient to answer the question.
The belief is one of the features of scientism.  Logical Positivists were generally advocates of scientism.  But logical positivism has been considered pretty thoroughly refuted in philosophy circles since the middle of the last century.  Scientism lasted a bit longer as a popular view, and there are still some advocates of it today, but over the last two decades or so, its vocal defenders have mostly been cowed in intellectual discourse.  See Has Scientism drastically declined as a worldview in the last 100 years?

I use the word 'belief' to mean consciously chosen positions. I would call the things in your second point "unconscious assumptions."

@ScottRowe I subscribe to the "little scientist" theory of infant/child development.  We learn that the feel of covers on us IS covers, by first person empiricism with discovering what is on us, and how to move it, as infants.  Similarly to full bladder and bladder control.  And the relation between waking up, and where we were when we went to sleep, or woke up before.  And the solidity of floors.  That we embed conscious discoveries in unconscious operations is just taking advantage of "thinking fast" skills.  That we forgot how we did all this as infants is -- just fallible memory.

I would argue that from a logical standpoint, it would be a literal impossibility to never subject yourself to ANY beliefs. Even with a person such as myself, which is highly skeptical across the board, you exist in a world comprised  nothing but other people and massive amounts of information. Existing in a world such as that, life is largely built on relationships with other people. Relationships are a development built over time, on which communication is the fundamental aspect that dictates the quality of each relationship. Communication is information being passed between people. I don't believe it's possible to live an entire life without believing one word out of another person's mouth. You trust somebody because you're relatively close to them. You know they wouldn't lie to you. But the Truth is that you don't KNOW that. You trust them so you believe them. And that concept of trust likely spreads thinner and thinner the further outwards you move from your core social circle.
But if you're referring specifically to existential beliefs? Religious related subject matter? Or the stance between Flat-Earthers and astrophysicists? Probably a rare find but I'm sure some exist out there..

+1: good answer.

We should be consciously aware of relying on others (and our own) unconscious assumptions. Not being aware doesn't ensure your safety.

This was written for an earlier version of the question. The question has since been edited in a way that makes this answer seem non-responsive.
Yes, many beings live without beliefs, including some humans. There are states of coma and/or unconsciousness that humans can enter where we lose the ability to form beliefs.
Beliefs are not a prerequisite to life.

This is obviously a semantic nitpicking that doesn’t answer the question. Most of us do not spend our entire life in a coma or are unconscious, and the question isn’t “do we have beliefs in every single moment of life?”

If you agree with the last statement, then your answer stands as a needless nitpicking. The question has the obvious implication that he’s not talking about whether or not we have beliefs in a completely unconscious state

@Syed:  What Lowri means is: ONLY the brain-dead live without belief. She is right.

@Olivier5 the same way that a person who says “you can go some days without water” to the question “is water necessary for life?” is right. It misses the point of the question

I would venture that she IS saying that folks cannot live a normal, ordinary life without beliefs, but she does so using an ironic tone, by stating that only the brain-dead can live without beliefs. @Syed

@Olivier5 Being pedantic is not the same as being ironic, and a serious question does not deserve an ironic answer anyways. There’s the comment section for that. Lastly, your assumption is false anyways. She earlier stated that she intended to directly answer the question implying no irony but then deleted her comment, which is why it looks like I was talking to myself :)

A little charity is necessary to philosophical discussion. People are entitled to find the question funny.

Lowri, can you please edit your answer to say something about "leaps of faith"? Or are are you interpreting "belief" and "leap of faith" as interchangeable?

@Syed, philosophy is the art of semantic nitpicking.

@Olivier5 again, she deleted her original comment where she made no indication that it was a joke, and said she was directly addressing the question (have to type this out again since my comments often get removed randomly).

@Lowri, question edited ...

@Syed So, you don't believe in beliefs, or what?

@Olivier5 Lowri's answer does not say that only the braindead or comatose can live without beliefs. I agree entirely with Lowri's answer, but I do not agree with your rephrasing of it.

Alistair's input - MkIII
There is debate over whether one needs beliefs, faith, etc.
Which begs the question, how could one operate without beliefs, or faith?  If one wanted to?  Is it possible?
Well, perhaps one could use the Convictometer.  (I made it up).

Easiest way to explain it is by example.


We don't have to assign words to our levels of convictions, labelling them.  When we can express ourselves numerical with more precision and accuracy, and less risk of misinterpretation less chance of miscommunication.


Call it faith then, if you don't like the word "belief". There's always an alternative word at hand.

Faith is another word with baggage.  I like "conviction".  But I like numerically expressed degrees of certainty best... leaves no room for miscommunication.

'Conviction' has a lot of baggage too -- sounds straight out of a tribunal.

lol.  Yes.  But that's better than sounding straight out of a sermon.

If you like judges better than priests, yes.

@Olivier5 Beyond the (minor) question of which of priest vs judge is more undesirable, the bigger issue with numbers is that probabilities make sense under the assumption of a probability distribution. [Not my downvote]

@Rushi Anyone who studied logic and math knows that you need a starting point for any reasoning. Hence axioms.

"Words are so cheap, but they can turn out expensive. Words like 'conviction' can turn in to a sentence."

No, I don't think so. It's impossible to live a life without "beliefs" or "acts of faith", for several reasons that can be found in both philosophy and the Bible.

Human Nature and Inevitable Belief

Philosophy teaches us that belief is inherent in human nature. According to Jean-Paul Sartre, even in a context of atheism or absence of explicit religious belief, human beings make choices based on presuppositions, values and commitments that are implicit forms of faith. In other words, faith is not a phenomenon reserved for a specific religious sphere, but a fundamental driving force behind all human actions. Every decision, whether moral, ethical or existential, is based on deep-seated beliefs, even if these beliefs are not always formalized or conscious.

Faith in everyday life

Even outside the religious sphere, every human act involves an act of faith. For example, when we go to the doctor or take a flight, we have faith in the skills of the people involved and in the systems that support these activities. This kind of "faith" is everywhere in everyday life. The Bible recognizes this reality in verses like Proverbs 3:5: "Trust in the Lord with all your heart, and lean not on your own understanding." This passage invites active faith, even in non-spiritual areas, affirming that trust in higher principles (like God) guides our understanding and actions.

Biblical faith as the foundation of life

From a biblical perspective, Hebrews 11:1 tells us that, "Faith is the substance of things hoped for, and the evidence of things not seen." Faith, according to the Bible, is essential to understanding the world. Believers are called to live by faith in God and His promises, a fundamental act of the human condition as part of the relationship with God. The Bible therefore maintains that faith, far from being an option, is the very foundation of the Christian life. Even understanding and apprehending reality requires an act of faith in divine wisdom. Jesus himself teaches that faith is the key to understanding life and entering the kingdom of God (Matthew 17:20).

The question of neutrality

We might also ask: can we really live without beliefs? Even the rejection of religious or philosophical beliefs is in itself a position of faith. If someone says "I don't believe in anything", this position is based on a belief in the sufficiency of human rationality or empiricism. This position is, in fact, a form of belief that denies the need for a transcendent foundation.
So living without beliefs or acts of faith is not only impossible from a human point of view, it goes against the very nature of existence. According to the Bible, to live without faith in the spiritual or moral sense is to live without a true foundation. In Hebrews 11:6, it is written, "Now without faith it is impossible to please him; for he who draws near to God must believe that God exists and that he rewards those who seek him." So faith is not just an intellectual or emotional act, but a key to a fulfilled, moral life spiritually connected to God and His divine principles.

Affirming faith is one approach. But the alternative does not have to be affirming rationality. My sense of it is that I actually don't have very many options in most situations, and even less knowledge. By becoming more self-aware, I realize that rather than having to know or justify, I can accept that I don't have any influence on 99% of what happens to me. So I don't believe, affirm, trust or know, I just muddle through. It got me where I am today.

+1: Good, informed answer.

If "the rejection of religious ... beliefs is in itself a position of faith" then so also is the rejection of, say, the claim that the earth is flat, or of young earth creationism. And anyone who has faith in one statement has thereby rejected any statement that contradicts it. So it says very little to describe something as "the rejection" of anything, or as "a position of faith".

The answer to the question “can we live life without beliefs?” may be no.
But the answer to the question “can we live life without leaps of faith?” is certainly yes. Just because I can’t prove something with certainty, for example, that an invisible six headed goblin is not on my shoulder right now, does not mean that I have blind faith in the non existence of this being. For starter’s, it’s a more complex proposition, and more complex propositions are apriori more improbable as per Occam’s razor. You may disagree with this reason but this does not imply that my belief is a leap of faith since that typically involves believing in something without evidence.

But Occam's Razor leads to metaphysical solipsism. Ergo, believing in an external world is a leap of faith?

@user80226 Occam’s razor applies between hypotheses that explain the same thing. Solipsism does not generate or predict all the data in the universe. We’ve already talked about this. Either way, you can disagree with these reasons, but this doesn’t make them a leap of faith

"all the data in the universe" - This is vague, and question-begging depending on what you put in "the data." A theist can put experiences of God in the data, and suddenly you now need to explain God. A naturalist would reject that as part of the data. A metaphysical solipsist would likewise reject a natural external world as part of the data.

@user80226 you don’t need God to explain the experience of God. We have ordinary scientific theories and hallucinogenic and dreamlike experiences that have physical causes that explain that already

You don't need an external world to explain experiences of an external world. The experience of time and of an external world are brute facts of qualia experienced by this mind in the present moment.

@user80226 my interest is not debating this for the nth time. My answer was just to point out that you can live without “leaps of faith”

Fair enough (not my downvote).

Btw, how do you reconcile your answer with your earlier assertion that all of philosophy is about judgement calls and betting on things? Isn't that a leap of faith?

@user80226 I don’t think judgment calls or even making bets imply faith. I think if something requires faith it means you have no reasons for it

@Syed I don’t think judgment calls or even making bets imply faith. Small correction: I don’t believe judgment calls or even making bets imply faith . At which point: Hail Gödel! Hail Epimenides!!
